# how to get changed folders in a PR in github actions?

Tags: github, terraform, github-actions

I want to check terraform fmt and KICS scan on changed folders in a PR with github actions.  I am not able to
following is my workflow. also folder structure is

- Modules
- Resource usage

I want to get the changed folders in above two main folders in a PR. after that i want to copy .tfvars file from resource usage to modules folder for KICS scan. Finally i want to check terraform fmt on all the changed folders.
You can check the workflow below

```yaml
name: Find Changed Files in PR
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  find-changed-files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Find Changed Files
        id: changed-files
        run: |
          base_branch="${{ github.base_ref }}"
          pr_branch="${{ github.head_ref }}"

          changed_files_module="$(git diff --name-only $base_branch $pr_branch -- 'Modules/')"
          changed_files_resource="$(git diff --name-only $base_branch $pr_branch -- 'Resource usage/')"

          echo "changed_files_folder1=${changed_files_module}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "changed_files_folder2=${changed_files_resource}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Print Changed Files
        env:
          changed_files_folder1: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.changed_files_folder1}}
          changed_files_folder2: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.changed_files_folder2}}
        run: |
          echo "Changed files in folder1 ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.changed_files_folder1 }}"
          echo "Changed files in folder2 ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.changed_files_folder2 }}"
```

Comment: Why did you have these two environment variables in the "Print changed files" step and then print the changed files with the outputs from the previous step?

Comment: Why only do `terraform fmt` in the changed files? you should do that on all

Comment: I am new to this Github actions, If you understood the questions please provide an answer. Also there are some errors on rest of the branch so i just need to check terraform fmt on changed files in a PR so that reviewer can approve.